Double join on a SQL table
I have the following SQL table:
propals:



id
ref




1
propal_1


2
propal_2


3
propal_3



orders:



id
ref




1
order_1


2
order_2


3
order_3



invoices:



id
ref




1
invoice_1


2
invoice_2


3
invoice_3



element_element:



sourcetype
fk_source
targettype
fk_target




propal
1
order
1


order
1
invoice
1


propal
2
order
3


order
3
invoice
3



I would like this result:



propal
order
invoice




propal_1
order_1
invoice_1


propal_2
order_3
NULL


propal_3
NULL
NULL


NULL
order_2
NULL


NULL
order_3
invoice_3


NULL
NULL
invoice_2



(I want all the orders, all the invoices and all the propals) event if they are not present in element_element table.
I tried this:
SELECT p.ref, o.ref, f.ref
FROM propals 
LEFT JOIN element_element ee on ee.fk_source = p.id and ee.sourcetype = "propal"
LEFT JOIN orders AS o ON o.id = ee.fk_target
LEFT JOIN element_element ee2 on ee2.fk_source = o.id and ee2.targettype = "invoice"
LEFT JOIN invoices AS i ON i.id = ee2.fk_target

But i get this:



propal
order
invoice




prop1
order_1
invoice_1


prop_2
order_3
NULL


propal_3
NULL
NULL



Obviously there is a way to get the desired result, i just can't figure it out.
Thanks for your help.

For the 2nd line of desired results, given the last line of element_element it seems like invoice 3 should be listed.

Also: this would be easy in any other database but MySQL, because you could start from orders and add a full join to each of the other tables.

I think, should be (propal_2, order_3, invoice_3) and row(NULL, order_3, invoice_3) should be deleted. Please explain.

Your actual results are not possible. There's no prop1 or prop_2 in the original data, where are they coming from?

Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question, paragraphs 5 and 3.
